# How to convert a string to date/time stamp in PHP

Tags: php

I have a string which has the value '2015-06-04 00:00:00'

How can I convert this to a date/time stamp using PHP?

Many thanks,

Alec

Comment: [strtotime()](http://php.net/manual/en/function.strtotime.php)

Comment: Why are people posting answers \*smh\* mark as dupe and move along.

Answer (score 1):

Try this code

```
$time = strtotime('2015-06-04 00:00:00'); // convert to datetime
$date = date('Y-m-d H:i:s',$time);        // change format
```

Answer (score 0):

**got your answer you can convert it by use this**

```
$date = strtotime('2015-06-04 00:00:00');
echo $date;
```

Answer (score 0):

I always prefer to pass from a DateTime class.

```
php > $dateTime = new DateTime('2015-06-04 00:00:00');
php > echo $dateTime->format('d/m/Y');
04/06/2015
```